# How to use URL names in views?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have been following [this Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/), and I am trying to remove hardcoded URLs, but I can't make the reverse function work.

That's my detail view:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
try:
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
except Question.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Question does not exist")

# How it was before:
# return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

return HttpResponse(reverse('polls:detail', kwargs={'question': question}))

path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail')
```

This is the urls.py:

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

And this is the template for the detail view:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
<a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">Index</a>
</form>
```

Can somebody help me with that or give any tips?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original code was fine.  If you were in another view (say, the vote view) and wanted to redirect the user to the detail view, you could do this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:detail', args=(question.id,)))
```

Copied from part 4 of the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

The last line redirects the user from the vote view to the results view and uses reverse() to avoid hard-coding the url.